# What's an effective way to remove this stubborn burnt-on oil from a saucepan?

Tags: cleaning

I have a stainless steel saucepan that has dark burnt on oil around the sides. I'm assuming it's from cooking oil since I use oil in this saucepan a lot.

It seems to just keep building up and up and I can't get rid of it.

This morning I tried boiling 1cup water with 1cup distilled vinegar for 5 minutes, then adding baking soda. I emptied the water, then tried to scour it clean but it made very little difference.

Is there some industrial strength stuff I can buy to help me out here?

Here's a pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0LhK.jpg

Comment: If your pan is not aluminum then try some hot soda solution or some kind of stronger alkali. Vinegar doesn't help much and even less when boiled because it evaporates very quickly. Boiling with soda may work better. But again don't use hot alkali on aluminum.

Comment: I know your looks darker than the one in the duplicate target, but I it is basically the same thing, only yours is burnt more. And you won't get any answers other than those on the other questions anyway, based on my observation of 6 years of cleaning advice on this site.

Answer (score 1):

If your pan is truly stainless steel, you can get burned on brown and sticky oil off the sides with oven cleaner (US brand "EZ-off" or other brand). This product is definitely *not* recommended for other metals such as copper, aluminum, etc.. But true stainless steel, I have used it no prob. If you are in doubt, you can test a small amount out on an inconspicuous tiny spot at first.